# Node js callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var signupHelper = require('./util/signuphelper');

router.post('/signup', signupHelper.checkEmpty, signupHelper.test, function(req,res){   });
```

I'm new to node.js (don't know if it is called callback.). My problem is, when `signupHelper.checkEmpty` has no errors it doesn't return anything, so it cannot proceed to `.test`. How can i fix this? Cos if there's no error, I want to check the data if it doesn't exist in the db so I need to call signupHelper.test to check.

In my checkEmpty

```
exports.checkEmpty = function(req,res){ 
------- some code here -------  
if(errors.length > 0){
        req.flash('errors', errors);
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }
}

exports.test = function(req,res) { some code....}
```

Comment: If their is no error..Have you checked the result by consoling it in node server?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to use return after the if statement just to test so I can proceed to `signupHelper.test`. But it's not working. The browser keeps loading. But when it encounters error (the if statement is true) then the browser redirects (as expected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the next parameter in the router callback function, look at the next(); that comes from the router callback.

```
exports.checkEmpty = function(req,res,next){ 
------- some code here -------  
if(errors.length > 0){
        req.flash('errors', errors);
        res.redirect('/signup');
    }else{
        next(); // This will pass the route to the next callback in chain.
    }
}

exports.test = function(req,res,next) { some code....}
```